How to sum the number of a certain species caught each day in R
I have 25 yrs' worth of capture data that includes 12 different species. Currently, I have a line for each individual caught at each site and date. What it currently looks like:



Sampling_Site_ID
date
species
species_code




1
1998-05-27
Species 01
SP01


1
1998-05-27
Species 01
SP01


1
1998-05-27
Species 02
SP02


1
1998-05-27
Species 02
SP02


1
1998-05-27
Species 03
SP03


1
1998-05-27
Species 04
SP04


1
2006-08-20
Species 01
SP01


2
1998-05-28
Species 05
SP05



I am trying to sum the number of each species caught on each day, to get it down to one line per species for each date at each site. Below is an example of what I am trying to get it to look like:



Sampling_Site_ID
date
species_code
#_indiv




1
1998-05-27
SP01
7


1
1998-05-27
SP03
1


1
1998-05-27
SP04
2


1
1998-08-20
SP01
15


1
1998-08-20
SP05
3


2
1998-08-28
SP02
1



This is what I have tried so far, with ftc_capture_data being the original df:
library(dplyr)

formatted_capture <- ftc_capture_data %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  mutate(formatted_capture = sum(species))

but I got this error message:
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `formatted_capture = sum(species)`.
ℹ In group 1: `date = 1998-05-27`.
Caused by error in `sum()`:
! invalid 'type' (character) of argument
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

I am trying to get it in the formatted_capture df because I will be needing to add other columns as well, but I am stuck at this point and need help. How can I resolve this?

sum() is a mathematical operation on numbers, R can sum 2 and 3, it can't sum "Species 01" and "Species 02".

What you can do is get the number of rows per group, which dplyr has a shortcut for, n(), as in ftc_capture_data %>% group_by(Sampling_Site_ID, date, species_code) %>% summarize(n_indiv = n()), or it has an even shorter cut of count(), ftc_capture_data %>% count(Sampling_Site_ID, date, species_code)

Thank you! I don't know why I was thinking sum, but your count helped. Much appreciated!

Based on your example it looks like you are trying to get a count of the number of rows by Sampling_Site_ID, date, species_code:
library(dplyr)

df |>
  count(pick(-species))

Output
  Sampling_Site_ID       date species_code n
1                1 1998-05-27         SP01 2
2                1 1998-05-27         SP02 2
3                1 1998-05-27         SP03 1
4                1 1998-05-27         SP04 1
5                1 2006-08-20         SP01 1
6                2 1998-05-28         SP05 1

Data
df <- structure(list(Sampling_Site_ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L), date = structure(c(10373, 10373, 10373, 10373, 10373, 10373, 
13380, 10374), class = "Date"), species = c("Species 01", "Species 01", 
"Species 02", "Species 02", "Species 03", "Species 04", "Species 01", 
"Species 05"), species_code = c("SP01", "SP01", "SP02", "SP02", 
"SP03", "SP04", "SP01", "SP05")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

